# How to hit two URLs one after another in PHP

Tags: php

I have two URLs I want to hit one by one and after hitting, pdf get downloaded. But if I use header location with `false` - it gives me an error in the browser: localhost sent an invalid response.

ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_LOCATION

```
 header('Location: '.$pdf1); 
 header('Location: '.$pdf2, false);
```

I also used

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
         window.open('".$pdf1."', '_blank')
         window.open('".$pdf2."', '_blank')
</script>
```

But if the pop up was blocked it don't get downloaded automatically.I want to get in downloaded automatically even if the pop up was block.

Comment: Can't you add a redirect parameter to the end of the first url? Read it when processing the page and redirect accordingly from there. E.g 'Location: '. $pdf1 . '?redirect='.  $pdf2

Answer (score 1):

No, this doesn't work. You can only tell the browser to redirect to one location. If you want to redirect somewhere else after, the second page has to redirect to the third.

Since you intend to download 2 pdfs at once, you have to use a different mechanism. There's javascript API's to initiate a download for example.

Comment: No, not really. I just answered your initial question which was "why this doesn't work". Sorry about that :/